# Is it possible to embed a Flex Assets Class in a CSS declaration?

Tags: css, apache-flex, embed, assets

I have an SWC which includes a number of Assets for my project.  Within this SWC is also a static AS file which contains Class declarations for each image in the library.

For example, the SWF contains these images:

```
/assets/foo/bar/img1.jpg
/assets/foo/bar/img2.jpg
```

And it includes an AS file which is like this:

```
[Embed(source="/assets/foo/bar/img1.jpg")]
public static const IMG_1:Class;

[Embed(source="/assets/foo/bar/img2.jpg")]
public static const IMG_2:Class;
```

I would like to create a CSS declaration which uses these two images, but I don't want to embed the full path.  Is it possible to do something *like* this?

```
<mx:Style>
    .mySampleStyle {
        upIcon:   Assets.IMG_1;
        downIcon: Assets.IMG_2;
    }
</mx:Style>
```

At the moment, this particular syntax is invalid -- I'm getting compile errors for the "." character in the style declaration.

Is there another way of doing this *without* embedding the path (e.g. `upIcon: Embed(source="/assets/foo/bar/img1.jpg")`) in the CSS?

Comment: It seems you want to embed an instance of a class.  I'm not sure if that is possible.  But, take a look at ClassReference to leverage a class inside a style sheet.

Comment: @Flextras, good point -- I forgot about ClassReference. I'm getting a "definition Assets.IMG_1 could not be found" error.  I expect it isn't able to trace the class down to the AS file.  I'll likely just stick to embedding the icons in the MXML tag declaration rather than in a CSS.

Comment: @Flextras, if you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept it. I can't find anything else to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

As stated [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/flexcoders/message/158711) in order to reference class member of type Class using ClassReference in CSS, you should used "_" instead of "." in the fully qualified name of the field you want to use.

In your example,

```
<mx:Style>
.mySampleStyle {
    upIcon:   ClassReference("Assets_IMG_1");
    downIcon: ClassReference("Assets_IMG_2");
}
```

should works.